# Convert HEXTORAW value to TIMESTAMP

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql

I am working on some analysis tools and I have a specific situation where I have a value that is represented using the HEXTORAW Oracle function as follows:

```
HEXTORAW('7876031b0d233900786450')
```

This value represents what would otherwise be written as `TO_TIMSTAMP('2018-03-27 12:34:56.00789')`.  So far I have found two ways to attempt to convert this HEXTORAW value:

- Using `dbms_stats.convert_raw_to_date`
- Using `dbms_stats.convert_raw_value` in a PL/SQL block

In both cases, the return value doesn't have the fractal seconds portion of the timestamp and I suspect this is likely due to the underlying calls relying on a `DATE` data type rather than a true `TIMESTAMP` data type.

Does anyone know if there is another PL/SQL package function that could be used to decode the raw value back to a complete timestamp that includes the fractal seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a function that converts a hex-string to a `TIMESTAMP` but you can easily calculate the `TIMESTAMP` value.

Convert the first 7 bytes to a `DATE` and then cast it to a `TIMESTAMP(9)` (which will have fractional seconds of 0) and then you can convert the last 4 bytes to a number, which represents the number of nanoseconds and then add that to the timestamp:

```sql
SELECT CAST(
         DBMS_STATS.CONVERT_RAW_TO_DATE(HEXTORAW(SUBSTR(hex_value,1,14)))
         AS TIMESTAMP(9)
       )
       + INTERVAL '1' SECOND(9)
         * TO_NUMBER(HEXTORAW(SUBSTR(hex_value,15,8)), 'XXXXXXXX') / 1e9
         AS timestamp_val,
       hex_value
FROM   (
  SELECT '7876031b0d233900786450' AS hex_value FROM DUAL
)
```

Outputs:

> | TIMESTAMP_VAL | HEX_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2018-03-27 12:34:56.007890000 | 7876031b0d233900786450 |

and

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value TIMESTAMP(9));
INSERT INTO table_name (value) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2018-03-27 12:34:56.007890000');

SELECT value, DUMP(value,16) FROM table_name
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | DUMP(VALUE,16) |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2018-03-27 12:34:56.007890000 | Typ=180 Len=11: 78,76,3,1b,d,23,39,0,78,64,50 |

Which has the same timestamp and same byte values.

---

If you want to wrap it into a function then:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION hex_to_timestamp(
  hex_value IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN TIMESTAMP DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN CAST(
           DBMS_STATS.CONVERT_RAW_TO_DATE(HEXTORAW(SUBSTR(hex_value,1,14)))
           AS TIMESTAMP
         )
         + INTERVAL '1' SECOND
           * TO_NUMBER(HEXTORAW(SUBSTR(hex_value,15,8)), 'XXXXXXXX') / 1e9;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e8cc43823b34a5e4acc8ce6e0269ee21)*

---

## Update

Perhaps the "simplest" method is to use something that will already convert a byte string to a timestamp. In this case, the Java class `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP` has a constructor that takes a byte array (and there is a similar constructor for `oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ`).

Therefore, if you have Java enabled in the database, you can use a small class to convert the hex-string to a byte array and then to wrap the constructors in functions:

```sql
CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED HexToTimestampConverter AS
import oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP;
import oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ;

public class HexToTimestampConverter {
  public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
      data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                           + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
  }

  public static TIMESTAMP hexToTimestamp(final String hex)
  {
    return new TIMESTAMP(hexStringToByteArray(hex));
  }

  public static TIMESTAMPTZ hexToTimestamptz(final String hex)
  {
    return new TIMESTAMPTZ(hexStringToByteArray(hex));
  }
}
```

Then you can create an SQL function to call the Java code:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION hex_to_timestamp( in_value IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN TIMESTAMP
AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'HexToTimestampConverter.hexToTimestamp(java.lang.String) return oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP';
/
```

And for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION hex_to_timestamptz( in_value IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'HexToTimestampConverter.hexToTimestamptz(java.lang.String) return oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ';
/
```

*(Note: you probably want to add some error checking to check that the string is hexadecimal and of the correct length.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cfaacaf41055348ac0d49ae4636852c0)*

Comment: One follow-up question, what about if the hextoraw value is a timestamp with time zone, it appears there are 2 additional bytes at the end, any idea how those are to be converted?

Comment: @Naros Updated - use Java inside the database.